# LibGDX: Is there a maximum amount of vertices for a PolygonShape?

Tags: libgdx, box2d

When you use `PolygonShape.set(Vector2[] vertices)`, is there a limit of vertices of the array which is passed to the method?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `set` on `com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.PolygonShape` calls `set` on `org.jbox2d.collision.shapes.PolygonShape`, which does check the `Settings.maxPolygonVertices` (see [`PolygonShape`](https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/src/main/java/org/jbox2d/collision/shapes/PolygonShape.java#L120) source).

Thus, unless you've set `org.jbox2d.common.Settings.maxPolygonVertices` to something yourself, the number of vertices needs to be between 3 and 8 (inclusive) as the default is set to

```
/**
 * The maximum number of vertices on a convex polygon.
 */
public static int maxPolygonVertices = 8;
```

Be careful about changing that number as it has an impact on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Method that you mentioned looks like this:

```
public void set (Vector2[] vertices) {
    Vec2[] v = new org.jbox2d.common.Vec2[vertices.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        v[i] = new Vec2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y);
    }
    shape.set(v, v.length);
}
```

Other methods in `PolygonShape` and her parent - `Shape` don't have the `length` limits too. I'm 100% sure that `PolygonShape` has no limit of vertices :_)