# How can I represent collision for an object needing more than PolygonShape's maximum of 8 vertices?

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

This is a part of map (it is a cave) of my LibGDX game (using Box2D): 
[image]

I would implement a PolygonShape as the black part of the map to prevent the whatever moves (for example a ball) inside the cave from leaving it.

This is an example of my PolygonShape like I would draw it (with 100 vertices): [image]

The problem is that Box2D doesn't allow me create it with not more than 8 vertices...

How can I fix this thing?

Sorry, my English isn't very good. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGDX: Is there a maximum amount of vertices for a PolygonShape?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/127797/libgdx-is-there-a-maximum-amount-of-vertices-for-a-polygonshape)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there a way in box2d to create a PolygonShape with more than 8 vertices?

Comment: Create a mesh instead if a polygon

Comment: I fixed it ,I created a ChainShape but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polygon shapes are normally limited by the internal `b2_maxPolygonVertices` setting (in the C++ library code), which as of Box2D 2.3.2 is set to 8.

The other problem though is that polygon shapes must be convex. What you're were trying to use a polygon for though looks to be a concave shape. For concave, static (immovable), shapes, the Chain Shape is the way I'd go.

From your comment, it looks like you have since decided on using ChainShape too.